# Ubuntu 10.04 SNMP No Change In ifInOctets / ifOutOctets

Tags: ubuntu, snmp, cacti

I have succesfully set up cacti on 3 different Ubuntu machines here to monitor bandwidth usage.  Upon trying to set it up on a remote machine, the bandwidth counter does not change.

`#snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10; sleep 10; snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10`

result

```
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.1 = Counter32: 221594
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.3 = Counter32: 6670994
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.4 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.5 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.6 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.1 = Counter32: 221594
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.3 = Counter32: 6670994
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.4 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.5 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.6 = Counter32: 0
```

Given a little time - 15 minutes or so, it does change.  I've purged and reinstalled identically to the other machines with no success.  I've also tried the 64 bit counters with no luck either.  Utilizing v1 & v3 also produces the same result.

Using `ifconfig`

Gives:

```
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:320474 errors:0 dropped:29 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:433453 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:22979993 (22.9 MB)  TX bytes:407158360 (407.1 MB)
Interrupt:44
```

a few seconds later:

```
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:323653 errors:0 dropped:29 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:436633 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:23186461 (23.1 MB)  TX bytes:407336648 (407.3 MB)
Interrupt:44
```

Data is being moved, just not registering with snmp.

snmpd.conf:

```
rocommunity  public
syslocation  "Over Here"
syscontact  someone@somewhere.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem myself, after searching around a lot and thinking that the problem was similar to this:

http://www.fineconnection.com/How_to_set_the_net-snmp_agent_update_or_counter_refresh_interval

I looked at the syslog file and realized the snmp was unable to access /proc/net amongst other things.

I am not sure if this default config has been fixed for the latest release, but after playing about the the permissions, I have got it to work again.